# How do I connect to a MySQL database in Pycharm using the terminal

Tags: mysql, pycharm

I'm trying to connect to my database in the terminal in pycharm but all it gives me is:

```
'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What do I do?

Comment: What OS are you using? How did you install MySQL?

Comment: Windows. I downloaded the installer here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/. It works with cmd just not the pycharm terminal

Comment: Please, navigate to `File | Settings | Tools | Terminal | Environment variables | Edit environment variables icon`. Is Include system environment variables option enabled? Do you see the path to MySQL on PATH variable? Does it work if you copy PATH variable and add it to User environment variables?

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I've been stuck in this since this morning. Again thank you very much